# Convert Html List to Select Using Jquery with HTML in seperate file

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to convert a UL to a Select Menu using Jquery.  The tricky part it the UL is contained in a separate html file.

For example:

In Separate file: SomeFile.html

```
<ul id="UlExample" class="UlExample">
<li id="1" class="liClass"><a href="#" class="ExampleLink">1</a></li>
</ul>
```

This gets imported and the text from each li(a) gets added to an existing select list(ExampleSelect1) as an option.

```
<select Name="ExampleSelect1" id="ExampleSelect1" class="ExampleSelect>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  I will need to use it once when the page loads and once again when an option is selected from the newly populated select menu.

Comment: Hello again, Thank you for the posts. It turns out the issue I am having is not with the exact code but with how i am trying to execute it. No matter what I do, I have to break the process up to make it work. For example, I do the .load command with .ready and then i select and modify the text with a "Populate" Button OR I make two buttons, one for the .load, and the other gets the text and adds it to the select. Does Anyone Know why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less is thus:

1. [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) the file "somefile.html" in a container
2. select the **a**  element of the file imported
3. for each element create a option element in your select element

```js
var select = $(".ExampleSelect");
$(".container").load("somefile.html")
$(".container .UlExample li a").each(function(){
  var textLink = $(this).text();
  var opt= $("<option />").attr("value", textLink).text(textLink);
   select.append(opt);
 })
```

```css
.container
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<select Name="ExampleSelect1" id="ExampleSelect1" class="ExampleSelect>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello again, Thank you for the posts. It turns out the issue I am having is not with the exact code but with how i am trying to execute it. No matter what I do, I have to break the process up to make it work. For example, I do the .load command with .ready and then i select and modify the text with a "Populate" Button OR I make two buttons, one for the .load, and the other gets the text and adds it to the select. Does Anyone Know why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out jQuery load() http://api.jquery.com/load/

```js
// You would load the file into an element like this
// $('#UlExample').load('UlExample.html', function() {
  
  $('#UlExample').find('li').each(function() {
    var val =  $(this).find('a').text();
    $('#ExampleSelect1').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
  });
// });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="UlExample" class="UlExample">
    <li id="1" class="liClass"><a href="#" class="ExampleLink">1</a></li>
    <li id="2" class="liClass"><a href="#" class="ExampleLink">2</a></li>
</ul>

<select Name="ExampleSelect1" id="ExampleSelect1" class="ExampleSelect">

</select>
```

Comment: Hello again, Thank you for the posts.  It turns out the issue I am having is not with the exact code but with how i am trying to execute it.  No matter what I do, I have to break the process up to make it work.  For example, I do the .load command with .ready and then i select and modify the text with a "Populate" Button OR I make two buttons, one for the .load, and the other gets the text and adds it to the select.  Does Anyone Know why this would be?